# What control algorithm can I use to stabilize a ticker?

Tags: algorithm

I'm attempting to build an algorithm for a ticker. The ticker has to emit ticks at a varying rate between a minimum, and a maximum interval between ticks. Every time a tick comes out, it triggers a load action on the system (triggering an expensive fetch). Fetching too often will result in this load time going up, and potentially hurting other consumers of the server. I want an algorithm that comes up with a stable speed to trigger this ticker and avoid overloading the server.

I've looked at proportional controllers, and PID controllers, but neither are obvious tools. Am I missing something?

Comment: How much data gets fed? Divide your server maximum load by the size of the data and you got your maximum amount of simultanous 'connection' adjust your tick speed to never exceed this?

Comment: Basically - I have a bunch of clients (100+) that are polling a server. The response time depends on two things: (1) How busy the endpoint is. (2) What data there is to serve. I can't introduce centralized rate limiting because it's not actually my software. So, this is non-trivial.

Comment: The tickers are on the client side? Try having the server suggest a minimum time to next request. Are the answers to different clients identical?

Comment: The clients are client side. The server can't be modified.